# Using recursion to find maximum difference between node and its ancestor in a binary tree

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, global-variables, binary-tree

I am working on finding maximum. difference between node and its ancestor. Here is my logic,

a.) for each node find minimum element in left subtree, call it `res1`

b.) Similarly, for each node find minimum element in right subtree, call it `res2`

c.) then find the `result` as `max(root-res1, root-res2)` and make sure to update result with the highest value found so far.

Here is my code;

```py
class Node:
    #global result
    result = -9999

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def max_diff(self, result):

        if self.left is None and self.right is None:
               return
        if self.left is not None:
               res1 = self.left.min_elem() /* find minimum in left subtree */
        else:
             res1 = math.inf
        if self.right is not None:
                res2 = self.right.min_elem() /* find minimum in right subtree */
        else:
             res2 = math.inf

        result = max(result, max(self.data - res1, self.data - res2)) /* update result */
        print(result)
        if self.left is not None:
                self.left.max_diff(result)
        if self.right is not None:
                self.right.max_diff(result)
        return

     def main_fn(self):
        
        self.max_diff(result)
        return result 


class Tree:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root


node = Node(2)
node.left = Node(8)
node.left.left = Node(3)
node.left.right = Node(-2)
node.right = Node(0)
node.right.right=Node(5)

mytree = Tree(node)

resultnew= mytree.root.main_fn()
```

My question is how can I return the value in the variable `result`. To the best of my knowledge, since `result` is a parameter of the method, `max_diff`; it won't be suitable to have `return result` in the end of the method. Can I please get some help here. thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since `max_diff` is a recursive function, you are correct: `return` cannot be returned directly as you drafted it.

Since Python does not allow passing variables by reference (like pointers in C++ for example), one valid workaround would be to use a mutable object (meaning it allows in-place modification of the content), like a Python `list` for example.

We can turn `return` into a `list` of only 1 element by updating one line in your initial `max_diff()` function:

Change `result = max(result, max(self.data - res1, self.data - res2))` to `result[0] = max(result[0], max(self.data - res1, self.data - res2))`

Then you can call this updated `max_diff()` method this way:

```
result = [math.inf] # some init value
root_node.max_diff(result) # run the recursion, updating the result list
print(result[0]) # get the first element as output
```

Key idea here is to turn `result` into a `list` (of 1 element), which is mutable, and getting final output back from `result[0]`

Comment: appreciate your response. But it seems my logic is not updating the variable `result ` properly. I have edited my code above with more details. The maximum difference here shd be 10, but the value for result is giving me 4. Is it possible you can help me here? I am in the learning phase of binary trees and how to update parameters in recursion.

Answer (score 0):

When `result` is a parameter, it is a local variable to that function, so *assigning* something to it will not help to pass a value back to the caller.

Another issue is that your code finds the *minimum* value in a subtree, but does not consider that the maximum difference could be determined by a *maximum* value in a sub tree. Both could be relevant.

I would try to avoid using a class `result` attribute in your `Node` class, since that will become problematic when you have more than one tree to inspect.

The insight you could use here is the following:

Instead of trying to "bubble up" what the most extreme value is in a subtree, "sift" down what the two extremes are (min and max) on the path you have followed to descend down the tree. Whenever you reach a leaf, you can easily deduct the maximum difference from those two extremes and return it.

The caller can then compare the two returned values (from left and right) to keep the greatest of the two and return that.

Here is an implementation:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def max_diff(self, low=None, high=None):
        if self is None:
            return None if low is None else high - low
        low = self.data if low is None else min(low, self.data)
        high = self.data if high is None else max(high, self.data)
        return max(
            Node.max_diff(self.left, low, high),
            Node.max_diff(self.right, low, high)
        )

# Example tree
root = Node(2,
    Node(8,
        Node(3),
        Node(-2)
    ),
    Node(0,
        None,
        Node(5)
    )
)
result = root.max_diff()
print(result)  # 10
```

Comment: appreciate you sharing your solution. One ting I am not being able to follow; what is `high` and `low`. are they values for largest and smallest values in a subtree.
can you plz clarify? thanx

Comment: They are the least and greatest on the  current path from the root.

Comment: It is the opposite approach: not the extremes of the subtree, but the extremes on the path down to the current node. As I wrote in my answer: *"Instead of trying to "bubble up" what the most extreme value is in a subtree, "sift" down what the two extremes are (min and max) on the path you have followed to descend down the tree. Whenever you reach a leaf, you can easily deduct the maximum difference from those two extremes and return it."*